# Issues in producer consumer by using java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the code for producer consumer problem, where producer produce the item three times then only consumer consume the item one time. The below code is working fine as a requirement but main thread is not going to stop. I don't know why it is not going to stop, I am not able to catch. Could you please any one have look in the below code and correct it?

```
public class ProducerConsumerProblem
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    ProducerConsumerStack st = new ProducerConsumerStack();
    new ProducerThread(st);
    new ConsumerThread(st);

    }
}

class ProducerConsumerStack
{
    int x;
    boolean flag = false;
    int producedCount = 0;

    public synchronized void push(int x)
    {
    if (flag)
    { // flag==true
        try
        {
        wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    this.x = x;
    System.out.println(x + " is produced..");
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    this.producedCount++;
    if (this.producedCount == 3)
    {
        this.producedCount = 0;
        this.flag = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    }

    synchronized public void pop()
    {
    if (!flag)
    { // flag==false
        try
        {
        wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x + " is consumed.\n");
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    flag = false;
    notify();
    }
}

class ProducerThread implements Runnable
{
    ProducerConsumerStack st = null;

    ProducerThread(ProducerConsumerStack st)
    {
    this.st = st;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
    t1.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        st.push(a++);
    }
    }
}

class ConsumerThread implements Runnable
{
    ProducerConsumerStack st = null;

    ConsumerThread(ProducerConsumerStack st)
    {
    this.st = st;
    Thread t2 = new Thread(this);
    t2.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        st.pop();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you say, "the main thread is not going to stop."  The main() routine in your program creates three objects, and then it exits.  What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: P.S., I see a potential problem in your code:  It's where the constructor of an object executes `new Thread(this).start();`.  Passing `this` to another thread in a constructor potentially allows the new thread to access the object in an uninitialized/incompletely initialized state.

Comment: @james large : Please run the same code and then see whether main thread is finishing or not. It's not going to finished at all.

Answer (score 0):

> @james large : Please run the same code and then see whether main thread is finishing or not. It's not going to finished at all.

I ran your program with one small change:  I added a thread that waits for for the main thread to die, and then prints a message:

```
public class ProducerConsumerProblem
{
    static volatile Thread mainThread;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        ProducerConsumerStack st = new ProducerConsumerStack();
        new ProducerThread(st);
        new ConsumerThread(st);

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                mainThread.join();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Aaaaaaaugh!");
            }
            System.out.println("Nighty Night!");
        }).start();

    }
}
```

It printed "Nighty Night!", proving that the main thread *did* in fact die.

The thread that did not terminate was the consumer thread:  By the time the producer thread had called `st.push()` fifteen times, the consumer thread had only completed five calls to `st.pop()`, and it was stuck in the sixth call, waiting for a notification that was never going to happen.

---

You might want to look at your `ProducerConsumerStack` class.  You put "stack" in its name, but it doesn't look like a stack to me.  For one thing, a stack should be able to store more than one item.  Yours can only store one.

Comment: Hi could you please convert your code with below java8 version, here you are using the lambda expression which is feature of java8, I am not working in java8 and also I do not have idea about lambda expression. Please convert it into java6.

Comment: @ManishKumar The lambda in my example is just a shorthand way of creating a `new Runnable` object.  The argument to the `Thread` constructor _must_ be a `Runnable`.  The compiler knows that, so it automatically creates an anonymous class that `implements Runnable`.  And, since the `Runnable` interface only defines one method, `run()`, the compiler knows that the body of the lambda must be intended as the body of that method.  Lambdas and _functional interfaces_ may seem a bit strange at first, but they're actually pretty simple once you get used to the idea.